# Inheritance understanding access denied for a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, project

I am a little bit stumped on this at the moment, From what i understand, the specific enemies inherit from the base enemy class, so when created they use the base enemy constructor, to create their own objects copies of the variables to work with. so when i use the inherited enemy's set_E function wound`t that set its own E_Damage and E_Health to work with? and if so why is it denying access to its own variables?

In the locals tab on visual basic each x object does indeed have its  own enemy variables, if i try direct access to the enemy class i get an access error, if i try  use the objects own i also get this error, what am i doing wrong?

**Base enemy class**

```
class Enemy
{
public:


Enemy();
~Enemy();


void set_E(float, float);
float get_E_H();
float get_E_D();


virtual void Battle() = 0;


float* E_Damage;
float* E_Health;
char* E_Descrip;
float* E_Attack;

};
```

Enemy distructor

```
   Enemy::~Enemy()
  {
    if (E_Damage != nullptr)
  {
    delete E_Damage;
    E_Damage = nullptr;
  }
  if (E_Health != nullptr)
  {
        delete E_Health;
    E_Health = nullptr;
  }
  if (E_Attack != nullptr)
  {
    delete E_Attack;
    E_Attack = nullptr;
  }

  if (E_Descrip != nullptr)
  {
    delete E_Descrip;
    E_Descrip = nullptr;
  }


}
```

Enemy Constructor:

```
E_Damage = new float;
E_Damage = nullptr;

E_Health = new float;
E_Health = nullptr;

E_Attack = new float;
E_Attack = nullptr;
```

Example inherited enemy.h

```
class T_Rex : private Enemy, private CS_Text_Adventure
{
public:

void T_Rex::set_E(float Dmg, float Health, T_Rex x);

T_Rex();


~T_Rex();


void Battle() override;

};
```

Example inherited enemy.cpp

```
void T_Rex::Battle()
{
    T_Rex x;

    x.set_E(15.0f, 100.0f, x);

    E_Descrip = "the passage way opens up to a tropical forrest";

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << x.E_Descrip << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        while(*fight == true)
        {
            *x.E_Attack = rand() % 100 + 0;

            if(*x.E_Attack >= 30)
            {
                *P_Health -= *x.E_Damage;
            }
            else if(*x.E_Attack < 30)
            {
                *x.E_Health -= *P_Health;
            }
            if(*P_Health <= 0)
            {

            *gamerun = false;
            }
            else if(*E_Health <= 0)
            {
            *fight = false;
            }
        }
        step++;
}
```

Unauthorized access on the pointer deference reassign:

```
void T_Rex::set_E(float Dmg, float Health, T_Rex x)
{
*x.E_Damage = Dmg;
*x.E_Health = Health;
}
```

Comment: What a mess. Why for the God's sake you create every variable through new? Why do you assign `nullptr` after each `new`?

Comment: At first there is no need to check for `nullptr` before every `delete`since `delete` performs the check anyway

Comment: It looks like you need a C++ book more than any specific advice, but if you want help with compilation errors, you need to copy and paste the complete unedited error messages to the question.

Comment: @n.m. it is amazing, OP does not understand basics and using multiple inheritance at the same time. He has all members public on one side and using private inheritance on another. Priceless.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take these two lines from your constructor:

```
E_Damage = new float;
E_Damage = nullptr;
```

First you allocate a single `float`, and make `E_Damage` point to it. Then you immediately make `E_Damage` a null pointer, so it no longer points anywhere valid. This leads to a memory leak.

Later you use this null pointer, which leads to *undefined behavior* and possible crashes.

For single values there's seldom a need to use pointers at all, especially in this case. Just declare `E_Damage` (and the other member variables) as normal non-pointer variables.